# How to mix dynamic and static navigation with zend framework 2

Tags: dynamic, static, navigation, zend-framework2

I have a project in zend framework 2 with a default navigation, connected with acl, and with the configuration corrected set (statically) from differente module.

I want that one of this module can add pages dynamically to the navigation.

For this module I have this section of module.config.ing

```
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'page-1',
            'label' => 'Page',
            'route' => 'page',
            'resource' => 'page',
            'privilege' => 'view',
            'order' => 40
        )
     )
 )
```

how and where can I add sub-pages to that page?

Comment: Dynamically how? Loading from a database?

Comment: yes, but it's not important, I just need some piece of code, I suppose to put in Module.php, where I get navigator from service manager and put my new pages under that static page. I already try in `getViewHelperConfig` but doen't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, I don't know if it's the best way, but it works.
In my Module.php i put:

```
public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager) {
    $events = $moduleManager->getEventManager();
    $events->attach(ModuleEvent::EVENT_MERGE_CONFIG, array($this, 'onMergeConfig'));
}

public function onMergeConfig(ModuleEvent $e) {
    $pages = array(
        'id' => 'page-1',
        'label' => 'Page',
        'route' => 'page',
        'resource' => 'page',
        'privilege' => 'view',
        'order' => 40
    )

    $configListener = $e->getConfigListener();
    $config = $configListener->getMergedConfig(false);

    // Modify the configuration; here, we'll remove a specific key:
    $config['navigation']['default']['team']['pages'][] = $pages;

    // Pass the changed configuration back to the listener:
    $configListener->setMergedConfig($config);
}
```

now i have just to load the pages dinamically.
If someone have a more complete and correct answer, please write it down.

Comment: the "just to load the pages dinamically" was to optimist. I need more help to do this.